# Get the number of Items in a Category

Tags: php, sql, categories

I am trying to get the number of items in each of my categories to show up next to the category name... here is the code i am currently using.  The SQL is setup to show the number of items...but I dont know how to write the PHP code to display it.  the PHP code currently only outputs the category names....but I need it to show the category...and then the number of items in each category....IE.

Things (10)
Thangs (6)
....and so on

```
<?php
  $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT category, COUNT(category) AS \"Total Items\"\n"
. "FROM products\n"
. "GROUP BY category");
    if ($results) { 
      //output results from database
      while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
      {                       

      echo '<div><a href="category.php?category='.$obj->category.'"><h1>'.$obj->category.'</h1></A></div>';
      }    
}    
mysqli_close();      
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should change "Total Items" to "Total_Items" remove space.

```
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT category, COUNT(category) AS Total_Items " . 
 "FROM products" . "GROUP BY category");
```

Then you can print in the format like (thing(10) an so on as under.

```
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
      {                       
echo '<div><a href="category.php?category='.$obj->category.'"><h1>'.$obj->category.'("'.$obj->Total_ITems.'")</h1></a></div>';

     }
```

Comment: That worked perfect....i actually did it like that originally but i guess the underscore in Total_items made the difference....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

your query will be

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT category, COUNT(category) AS Total_Items ...."
```

and in php

```
<?php echo $obj->Total_Items; ?>
```